# UINavigationBar on top of status bar after dismiss a modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a modal view controller and it is embed in a navigation controller a. I am presenting another navigation controller b, after navigation controller b is dismissed, the navigation bar is on top of status bar in navigation controller a. You can see the pic below. I am using iOS 8.0 to develop the app by the way.
[image: normal]

[image: after modal view controller dismissed]

Comment: could you try setting `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`  in your `viewWillAppear` for your view controllers and see if that helps ?

Comment: @Zhang It's not working.